# Selenium webdriver is unable to locate element in one cell of Jupyter Notebook and locates it in another cell

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook

I have a function:

```
def download_CSV_file():
     downloadCSV=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Download file in csv format')]")
     downloadCSV.click()
```

I am using the above function after a sequence of different functions:

```
chrome=webdriver.Chrome() 
chrome.get("https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm")
select_symbol('YESBANK')
select_time_period('24 Months')
select_getData() 
download_CSV_file()
```

It gives me the error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'Download file in csv format')]"}
```

However, when I call the function independently in another cell of my Jupyter notebook it does the job. What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it possible that your other selenium functions alters the DOM in any way so that the element cannot be found?

Comment: Yes. This was exactly the case. I used `time.sleep(5)` and it worked. Thanks a lot.